# Why hide div element on click is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hide

```js
function closepopup() {
  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="openpopup()">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="popupclose" onclick="$('.boxpopup').hide()">Foo bar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case element `<a class="popupclose" onclick="$('.boxpopup').hide()"></a>` is not working. I want to show "popup" element on click in box element and hide it on click in some graphic element in "popupclose" div.

Comment: There's a few issues in that logic, aside from missing a reference to jQuery and the missing implementation of `openpopup()`, the `a` is a child of the parent `div`, so both `openpopup()` ***AND*** `.hide()` will be called every time that `a` element is clicked. Also note that the `closepopup()` implementation will only work for the *first* `.popup` element in the DOM. If you have multiple, that won't work

Comment: There's no `class="boxpopup"` anywhere for `$('.boxpopup')` to select.